# Header location doesn't work in my wordpress plugin.

Tags: wordpress, header, location

I'm writing an Wordpress plugin. With this plugin I update some data. The query and updating works fine, but my header`("location: url");` doesn't work. If I place an echo, it won't give any error that the headers already send. It looks it doesn't do anything with those lines. My code...

```
<?php require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
$baanstatus_table=$wpdb->prefix . 'baanstatus';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$bijgewerkt =$_GET['bijgewerkt'];
$baanstatus= $_GET['baanstatus'];
$handicarts = $_GET['handicarts'];
$trolleys = $_GET['trolleys'];
$winterontheffing = $_GET['winterontheffing'];
$zomergreens = $_GET['zomergreens'];
$qualifying = $_GET['qualifying'];
$onderhoud_greens = $_GET['onderhoud_greens'];
$onderhoud_anders = $_GET['onderhoud_anders'];
$opmerkingen = $_GET['opmerkingen'];
global $wpdb;
$data_array =array('id' => $id, 
'bijgewerkt' => $bijgewerkt, 
'baanstatus' => $baanstatus, 
'handicarts' => $handicarts, 
'trolleys' => $trolleys,
'winterontheffing' =>$winterontheffing,
'zomergreens' =>$zomergreens,
'qualifying' =>$qualifying,
'onderhoud_greens' =>$onderhoud_greens,
'onderhoud_anders' =>$onderhoud_anders,
'opmerkingen' =>$opmerkingen
);
$where =array('id' => $id);
$wpdb->update( $baanstatus_table, $data_array, $where );
header("location:http://almeerderhout.fcklap.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-unique-identifier");
exit(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should try the javascript, instead of PHP location.

```
<?php
   echo '<script>location.href="http://almeerderhout.fcklap.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-unique-identifier";</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you

```
 <?php
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
?>
```

The above wordpress function will use to redirect [Codex Link function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Comment: Is not working.... Problem is that headers already been sent in file I need. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/almeer/domains/almeerderhout.nl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/baanstatus/index.php:86) in /home/almeer/domains/almeerderhout.nl/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896

Comment: In word press main plugin file avoid the free spaces at the starting line and ending line of program. https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin please see the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook your plugin to a proper Wordpress action to avoid the "headers already sent error" when trying to redirect.

I found that a good place to perform redirects is the `template_redirect` action, so you can write something like this:

```
function do_something_then_redirect() {

    // do something with $_GET or $_POST data

    // then redirect to some url defined in the $redirect_url variable
    wp_redirect($redirect_url);
    die;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'do_something_then_redirect');
```